# passing array from one viewcontroller to another

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have a custom tabBar class in which i switch three view controllers ,i am removing the presentview controller and presenting the other .
custom tabbar class
       -list
       -inbox
       -messages
now i have to pass an array from list to inbox 
i usually create an instance of the recieving class like

```
Inbox *inbox=[[Inbox alloc]init];
inbox.array=self.array;
```

but in this case its not working.the array in inbox class returns null when i nslog it

Comment: See post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478511/passing-array-between-view-controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok this worked when i passed the value to applicationdelegate and from the other class accessed from here.

Comment: can you provide the steps you followed to pass array from one view controller to another view ontroller.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check your property in Inbox class and check to see if self.array is not null.

Edit try: `inbox.array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.array]`

Comment: self.array is not null..i have nslogged it ,and i have set the @property(nonatomic,retain)nsarray array in inbox class.is it any problem in changing the views....usually this worked when i used pushviewcontroller

Comment: but the problem here seems to be inbox.array, that one is the one which doesn't look like it has been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Do you inherit or use the UITabBarController in your custom tabBar?

If you want to pass a variable between list<->inbox<->messages I would suggest that you implement a method in the tabBar that can be called from the subviews. The method would send the array to the appropriate subview.

Comment: its a uiviewcontroller that follows tabbardelegate protocol .its similar to http://www.wiredbob.com/blog/2009/4/20/iphone-tweetie-style-navigation-framework.html.