# How do you transfer data between UIViewControllers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Currently I am making a game for iPhone, and want each level to be on a different uiviewcontroller (I have tried putting them all on the same view controller, but this just makes it jumpy).  However, I need a way to get a high score in the level's view controller and send it back to the menu view controller.  I am using the code:

```
SecondLevelViewController *screen = [[SecondLevelViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];
[screen release];
```

to get to the viewcontroller and

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

to get back.  I am familiar with NSUserDefaults, which are what I am using currently to get high scores.  However, I know this code resets the level's view controller, that is still fine and even great because i want the level to reset-- but if just i could get data back that would be helpful.

Please put things in simple words, because I am very new to programming.

Thanks in advance!

Steve Becker

PS I am using xcode 4.0...

--------------------------------------------ALSO!!!-------------------------------------
The code I am using, I can only figure out how to get transitions "FlipHorizontal", "CoverVertical", and "CrossDissolve"...But I have seen many other cool transitions on the iPhone--like the page corner flipping like a page in a book.  If you know how to do these other transitions, please tell me!!!!  Greatly appreciated!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much more standard to have all of the levels on the same `UIViewController` unless the logic is so different that it's like playing different games. However, you could use a whole slew of different methods to achieve this. For example, you could use the [NSNotificationCenter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html), or a plist.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use [delegation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW18) or [`NSNotification`s](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043i) for this.

Answer (score 1):

you could also use a `singleton class` to modify and access the sharable data in any class of your projects,

Here is the good SO post on singleton class in objective - C

[Singleton shared data source in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355449/singleton-shared-data-source-in-objective-c)

**Edited:**

[What should my Objective-C singleton look like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like)

`Edited: for Curl page animation :` below is the link to blog tutorial and the source code.

http://blog.steventroughtonsmith.com/2010/02/apples-ibooks-dynamic-page-curl.html

Comment: :) i was just writing this, you surpassed me by seconds.

Comment: @KakoSquid: anytime Dude :) :)

Comment: @Steve Becker : Check my updated answer for curl page animation

Answer (score 1):

Think about the different view controllers like the mafia: every view controller is operating on a need-to-know basis.

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478511/passing-array-between-view-controllers/4482350#4482350) I gave before.